# C# Setup very basic reporting with dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, reportviewer

I'am trying to implement some basic report in my app. What I've already did:

- Setup new DataSet (contains only 1 table with 3 fields)
- Design simple .rdlc file according to dataset

[image]

Then add reportViewer control and point it to .rdlc file created.

[image]

I'am show form with reportViewer with following code:

```
FormReport formReport = new FormReport();
formReport.ShowDialog();
```

As a result I got an empty `reportViewer`; even without headings and dummy line object etc. Run out of ideas what is wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've solve it.
When loading report form i add following code:

```
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

And it works now. Don't know why Report Wizard don't add it automatically.

Comment: Thank you Mikey, there is restriction 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, but hey, you're on 87% now, that's plenty